# Finding a circle tangent to three given circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the position and the radius of the violet and blue circles.
I need to find the position of the pink circle which should touch all previous circles.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Represent the radius by an unknown, and apply the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the radii of the circles $R_a$, $R_b$ and $R_c$ and use the Pythagorean theorem one finds
$$ (R_a + R_b)^2 + (R_a + R_c)^2 = (R_b + R_c)^2 $$
Solving for $R_c$ yields:
$$ R_c = \frac{R_a(R_a+R_b)}{R_a-R_b}$$
If $R_a \neq R_b$. Filling in $R_a = 2$ and $R_b = 4$ (which I eyeballed from the picture) gives $R_c = 6$

Comment: Can you prove the triangle is right-angled though?

Comment: Since it has to touch all three blue circles (whose centers are aligned on the y-axis) and the problem is symmetric in the x-axis, the center of the purple circle should be on the x-axis. Hence the triangle is right-angled

Comment: wow. so simple. I felt that I had to use the Pythagorean theorem, but couldn't understand how to represent hypotenuse and second cathetus. Thanks a lot!