# Finding a circle tangent to two given circles and x-axis

Tags: geometry, circles

Given 2 circles with known radii and positions.

[image]

What is the position of the pink circle if it should touch the previous 2 circles and the x-axis?

A little bit more info:

- It is a special case for this one [previous related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733712/finding-a-circle-tangent-to-three-given-circles/2733736#2733736).
  But I find it difficult to represent AD, DB or DC cathetus.
- This also could be useful info [probably related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234777/chain-of-circles/235030#235030)

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/LCC.shtml

Comment: still have no idea how to solve this :(

Comment: What's wrong with the solution at the link I posted?

Comment: In your picture the circles are tangent and one of them is centered at the origin: can we assume that as true?

Comment: yes, but circle C should be tangent to the x-axis. In provided solution, m line is perpendicular to "my" x-axis. can you, please, shed some more light on this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C=(x,y)$ be the center of the pink circle, of radius $r_C=y$. Then we have:
$$
\cases{
x^2+y^2=(r_B+y)^2\\
x^2+(r_A+r_B-y)^2=(r_A+y)^2}
$$
This system is easy to solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: yes. thank you!